# TransactionSynchronization sallow RuntimeException that is thrown while afterComplete process

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

Spring has transaction synchronizer that eats Runtime Exception here are spring code that does this -

```
public static void invokeAfterCompletion(List<TransactionSynchronization> synchronizations, int completionStatus) {
        if (synchronizations != null) {
            for (TransactionSynchronization synchronization : synchronizations) {
                try {
                    synchronization.afterCompletion(completionStatus);
                }
                catch (Throwable tsex) {
                    logger.error("TransactionSynchronization.afterCompletion threw exception", tsex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

is there a way through which I know about exception thrown while afterComplete? I have considered solutions like thread locals but does spring provides a clean way of handling this?
any one?

### EDIT

The postCompletion method checks if rollback triggered and does some clean up. If clean up fails with an exception like Connection Reset or Network issue, I wanted to add retry mechanism in my code. Since postCompletion is called by third party code It throws an exception RollbackFailed. I want to catch that exception and add retry few more times as release resource is important for me.
reference to spring jira issue - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12560

Comment: Similar issue thread (without solution) is here. http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/21842-spring-jpa-transaction-code-swallows-exceptions

Comment: Are you asking because your code generates such exception or are you using a 3rd party-libs that is using that callback? In the former case, the javadoc is pretty explicit about what it does.

Comment: I am using a third party lib that can not be changed; it is throwing specialized exception that I need to catch.

Comment: What third party lib? What would you do with the exception exactly?

Comment: I have added above as part of EDIT section.

Comment: I see that you've [created an issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12560) now